# Trying to write a shell script to move most recent file from downloads to another folder

Tags: macos, shell, download, terminal, iterm2

I am trying to write a script that will find the most recently added item from my downloads folder and move to to another folder. I'm close but stuck on the final part. I'm doing this as an exercise to better learn iTerm2, not for practical reasons. I realize there are simpler ways to do this in browser.

```
ls -t1 /Users/name/downloads |  head -n 1 | > Users/name/targetfolder
```

Answer (score 0):

If the item is a file, you can pipe your `head` command to `cp` :

```
 ls -t1 /Users/name/downloads | head -n 1 | xargs cp -t Users/name/targetfolder
```

You may also add a test to check whether the item is a file or a directory :

```
last=$(ls -t1 . |  head -n 1)
todir=Users/name/targetfolder

[ -d $last ] && cp -r "$last" "$todir" || cp "$last" "$todir"
```

Answer (score -1):

You are correctly finding the most recent item with:

```
ls -t1 /Users/name/downloads |  head -n 1
```

However you are making mistake afer that.

What you can do is:

```
 mv $(ls -t1 /Users/name/downloads |  head -n 1) Users/name/targetfolder
```

Above is a standard `mv` command whose syntax is:

```
mv filename target_filename   # if you are renaming a file. Or,

mv filename target_dirname    # if moving the file to a different directory.
```

Anything command between `$()` is replaced by its output.

So `$(ls -t1 /Users/name/downloads |  head -n 1)` is replaced by the most recent file.

Hence, basically, the command means `mv most_recent_file Users/name/targetfolder`

Comment: I am getting this error -> mv: cannot stat 'filename': No such file or directory

`mv $(ls -t1 ~/Downloads |  head -n 1) ~/todelete` -> I executed this and got the above error.